# how to make pip respect the "CC" environment variable

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, distutils

I'm working in a very convoluted environment where different machines have access to different distributed file systems.

- Machine `A` has access to filesystem `X` and is used to install software on filesystem `Y`.
- Machine `B` has access to filesystem `Y`, but not `X`.

I'm working on machine `B`, and I find myself using python a lot. Sometimes, I need packages that are not preinstalled, so I use `pip install PKGXYZ --user` to install them locally. This generally works nicely, but there's a catch.

The python packages `distutils` and its monkey-patched derivative `setuptools` which are used by `pip` use the `distutils.sysconfig` functionality to get hold of compiler versions, paths, and somesuch. For this, they use the internal `Makefile` that was used to install python. While this is generally a good strategy, it fails with my concrete setup, because the paths in pythons internal `Makefile` point to filesystem `X`, which I do not have access to on my machine `B`. Hence, I find myself using the `--no-clean` option of `pip` and hacking the `setup.py` of the packages I want to install with snippets like this:

```
import re
import sys
import os
cc = os.getenv("CC")
if not cc:
    print("please set CC environment variable!")
    exit(0)
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars
for k,v in get_config_vars().iteritems():
    try:
        if "fsX" in v:
            newv = re.sub(r'/fsX/[^ ]*/g[c+][c+]',cc,v)
            get_config_vars()[k] = newv
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

such that I can use the `CC` environment variable to overwrite the default settings of the compiler path from pythons `Makefile` with something that works on my machine.

However, this is an ugly hack. There must surely be a nicer way to do this and make `pip` use some different compiler via some environment variable, config file or command line option. Or is there?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have compiler tools on system B, so one option would be to re-build python on your system using local tools and use that instead.

If you're only doing this for your user on you system, then you can even install it in your user's home directory to keep it completely out the way, and then set up your environment to use that. Or use virtualenv.

You can get and build a new Python install easily enough. For example for python 3.5.1 on Linux:

```
cd
mkdir src
mkdir -p local/python351
cd src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar -xf Python*.tgz
cd Python-3.5.1
./configure --prefix ~/local/python351
make
make install
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. While building a custom python version is surely an option, I am actually writing a package that depends on a python package that would need to be installed by the recipients, so I would need to provide some easy-to-follow instructions for this issue. Compiling your own python version seems to be overkill for the issue at hand, in my opinion.

Comment: And all the recipients will have the same issue, that their python installations were built with now unavailable tools? It seems a bit crazy to me, and perhaps if it's the way the machines are configured at your company you should look into fixing it, because it seems like you might have further problems in the future from it too. Could you not roll the change into a scheduled python upgrade perhaps?

Comment: Yes, all the recipients will have the same issue. And yes, it's a bit crazy. And yes, a fix of the setup is underway, but will take on the order of months to be deployed, whereas the software I am working on will be deployed on the order of weeks. So we need a working intermediate solution.